# Trying to understand how two relay lenses can be used in a light microscope to create a remote Fourier plane for easy access

Tags: microscopy

I am researching the use of relay lens systems to create an additional Fourier plane within a light microscope… to allow easy remote access for filters or masks. I have included some diagrams. One shows a simplified system for SSEE microscopy (Single Sideband Edge Enhancement). A Semicircular opaque mask beneath the condenser provides a type of asymmetric illumination on only the left side. In the Fourier plane (aka objective back focal plane) there is another semicircular filter to attenuate zero-order direct light on the right side (Carrier Attenuation Filter or CAF). This is a type of Fourier plane spatial frequency modulation. Two additional relay lenses can be used to allow a CAF independent of the objective assembly. The next diagram shows a folded version of a similar relay system made by Nikon in the 1970. It allows convenient placement of a special phase plate in a remote Fourier plane. A modern infinity-corrected instrument is made by Nikon (Eclipse 2i E model) with similar remote placement of phase plate/s, but I have not seen schematics for that relay system.

[image: simplified SSEE microscope]

[image: SSEE microscope with and without Fourier plane relay system]

[image: A folded relay system for finite-corrected microscope made by Nikon in the 1970's]

I am trying to understand whether these finite-system relays are the same as the 4f systems seen in texts. Some diagrams illustrate that the beam is collimated between the two relay lenses. Is so, how can those diagrams be reconciled to the Ellis diagram, e.g., where is the location of the Fourier plane between the relay lenses? Is there more than one way to tackle this problem ? I also noticed that SSEE relay lens R1 is placed before the image plane, whereas the 4f relays in some texts show the first relay lens placed after the image plane.  Any clarification would be appreciated.

Finally, I read that if the R1 lens is exactly the same as R2, but one is inverted, then the aberrations in R1 tens to be cancelled by R2 … Is this completely true or only partly true ? Do relay systems degrade image quality ?